# Kafka Producer Java and .NET CORE 2.1

Tags: java, .net-core, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Well, I'm doing a Benchmark about performance in Spring Kafka vs Confluent.Kafka 1.1.0 (.NET CORE 2.1).

I noted that Spring kafka write 1 million messages in 11 seconds and NETCORE in 1.58 minutes. The difference is much more than expected, in both producer configurations i didn't change anything, just use the default of driver.

**NETCORE 2.1 Configuration**

```
public static void produce()
        {
            var hostPort = "localhost:9092";
            var config = new ProducerConfig(
                 new Dictionary<string,string> { 
                     {"bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092"}
                }
            );

            Console.WriteLine($"Connecting in Kafka using host {hostPort}");

            try
            {
                using (var producer = new ProducerBuilder<Null, String>(config).Build())
                {
                    var startTime = DateTime.Now;
                    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
                    {
                        //send message to kafka broker without wait for any response
                        producer.Produce("netcore-topic", new Message<Null, string> { Value = $"Producing message {i} from .NET CORE 2.1" });
                        Console.WriteLine($"Producing message {i}");
                    }
                    var endTime = DateTime.Now;

                    Console.WriteLine($"Total time = {(endTime - startTime)}");

                    //avoid terminate program before messaged was delivered
                    producer.Flush(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(880));
                    Console.WriteLine("All messages sent");
                }
            }
            catch (ProduceException<Null, string> e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {e.Error.Reason}");
            }
        }
```

**And this is Spring Kafka Producer Configuration:**

```
 @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(
                ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
                "localhost:9092");
        configProps.put(
                ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                StringSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(
                ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                StringSerializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
    }
```

So, as you can see don't exists any different configurations. And the method producing the message is just a console write in both languages.

Exist any related slow issue in netcore driver or i need set better configuration in netcore driver ?

Comment: Where are you sending any data in the Java code?

Comment: I have a template.send() in my Application class, but I didn't post here

Comment: Well, all I can say is that adding print statements and time calculations will indeed slow things down. Spring might even be using a different thread for the producer

Comment: The send is performed on the caller's thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, the .NET `Console.WriteLine` is very slow, when i remove it the spend time decrease to 2 seconds.